# How Install Ubuntu 21.04 (Desktop) on Raspberry Pi 4 using Serial Console?

Tags: boot, serial, ubuntu, uart, serial-console

Hello how can I install ubuntu desktop 21.04 on raspberry pi 4 using serial console? I want to use the Raspberry Pi 4 UART pins to communicate using TTL to USB convert device to my windows 10 OS using PuTTY.

I tried configuring cmdline.txt and config.txt, I was able to communicate with the ubuntu 20.04 desktop installater, but I get stuck at "login" and "password".

How do I prepare the SD card files to add a valid "login" and "password" credentials so that I can be able to install ubuntu 20.04 desktop via serial?

Here is a pic:

https://preview.redd.it/psd8p03damb71.jpg?width=647&format=pjpg&auto=webp&s=6763fdfdf162e60e0d810c99a3ae791596399d05

Thanks.

Edit: I solved the problem.

I had to edit the boot files of the installer and add a root hash password to "etc/shawdow". Since ubuntu does not supply a default root password on it's installers.

Here is a video on how to do it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyG1bMk522I

Here is a pic me finally logging into the Ubuntu 21.04 desktop release installer as root via UART TTL Serial communication from PuTTY:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dvTU.jpg

All that is left is to finally install ubuntu 21.04 into the raspberry pi 4... all done heedlessly, thank goodness :)

Comment: What do you mean by "serial console"? Do you mean without using a monitor , keyboard and mouse? Do some Google searches and you'll find things like https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154768/can-you-install-ubuntu-on-the-raspberry-pi-4 Put some effort in then come back here with specific questions...

Comment: Enabling/disabling the serial console is done **the same way regardless of distro**, so the real question is how to enable the serial console.  The answer you are looking for is actually *in the question* of the duplicate (settings in `config.txt` and `cmdline.txt`).

Comment: I meant as "serial console" as in the using serial communication via the Raspberry Pi's UART pin connected to a TTL to USB converter device, I will use PuTTY as the serial console to communicate with the raspberry pi. I tried configuring the config.txt and cmdline.txt and in the serial console I am stuck with a login and password requirement. I tired all default password and login, none works. here is picture: https://preview.redd.it/psd8p03damb71.jpg?width=647&format=pjpg&auto=webp&s=6763fdfdf162e60e0d810c99a3ae791596399d05

Comment: Max, the question is now substantially different than originally.  It was about how to enable the serial console, and problem solved.  "How to log in to ubuntu via the serial console?" is a completely separate question and should be asked as such -- ie., *when you have a new question, ask a new question*, do not edit it into a previous one.  We do not have a run-on discussion format here. Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.

Comment: it is unclear what you mean by `install` ... the picture you attached shows boot messages and a login prompt

Comment: The problem is not solved, I am trying to install ubuntu 21.04 into raspberry pi 4 using the serial console and I do not want to use the server release build since it is a hassle to always install the desktop packages manually, I want to use the ubuntu desktop build and it can be done but you need to modify the boot files. I read a tutorial on how its done using ubuntu mate os. but for some reason the boot files modification for allowing the UART ports to work during boot has some kind of confliction with ubuntu 21.04 login. So this is very technical question and it seems everyone is confused.

Comment: Here is the Ubuntu Mate tutorial on how to install ubuntu mate on raspberry pi using only the serial console via the UART pins, its the only kind in the internet: https://limesdr.ru/en/2020/10/17/rpi4-headless-ubuntu/

Comment: The tutorial shows they are able to login to the Ubuntu mate via serial console using the login and password: "oem". This password however does not work for ubuntu 21.04. So I am assuming maybe I need to modify something specific for ubuntu 21.04 boot files to have the login work so that I can install ubuntu 21.04 using the serial console. So the question is still relevant, how does one installs ubuntu 21.04 using the serial port (UART Pins)?